# minikube and azure container registry

Tags: minikube

I am trying to get images in minikube from the Azure container registry. This keeps failing because not it says unauthorized.
unauthorized: authentication required

I used kubectl create secret to add the credentials for the registry but it keeps failing.

what I tried so far:

- I added the URL with and without https
- I added the admin user and made a new service principle
- I tried to add the secret to the default service account in hope something was wrong with the yaml
- used minikube ssh to see if could use docker login and docker pull (that worked).

Getting bit desperate what I can try next? how can I troubleshoot this better?

Comment: Salvaged link from @BinduChinnasamy's link-only answer (which may disappear soon): https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2375 (OP happens to be part of the discussion too, but I could not tell if it is the exact same issue or not)

Comment: i been involved in that discussion on github; finally got it working by generating a new secret in ACR

Answer (score 4):

The `kubectl create secret` command should have produced a ~/.dockercfg file, which is used to authenticate with the registry for subsequent `docker push` and `docker pull` requests.

I suspect you may have created your secret in the wrong namespace, given that your `docker login` and `docker pull` commands worked.

> Pods can only reference image pull secrets in their own namespace, so this process needs to be done one time per namespace.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-azure-container-registry-acr

Comment: i only have one namespace at the moment but will check to be sure latre today as soon behind a computer again

Comment: This is great. It does however require adding imagePullSecrets to the container specs which aren't needed in cloud environments where most cloud providers seem to provide a docker config with working credentials. If anyone knows of a method that uses your local docker config like the remote environments do that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a secret and save it at your kubernetes context (in your case minikube context).

1. Firstly be sure that you are pointing to the right context by running `kubectl config get-contexts` and `kubectl config use-context minikube` to change to minikube context.
2. Create a secret in minikube context by running `kubectl create secret docker-registry acr-secret --docker-server=<your acr server>.azurecr.io --docker-username=<your acr username> --docker-password=<your acr password>`. This command generates **acr-secret**.
3. Import the `acr-secret` into deployment yml files by using the imagePullSecrets inside each template.spec tag:

```
    imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a much simpler answer. First you need to install the Azure CLI and login

```bash
az login
```

After that, you can get the credentials for your Azure Container Registry

```bash
az acr login -n yoursupercoolregistry.azurecr.io --expose-token
```

This will give you something like that:

```json
{
  "accessToken": "averylongtoken",
  "loginServer": "yoursupercoolregistry.azurecr.io"
}
```

With this information, you can enable registry-creds and configure a **Docker Registry** (and not a Azure Container Registry)

```bash
minikube addons enable registry-creds
minikube addons configure registry-creds
```

You have to enter your server URL and `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as client ID.

```
Do you want to enable Docker Registry? [y/n]: y
-- Enter docker registry server url: yoursupercoolregistry.azurecr.io
-- Enter docker registry username: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

And at the end paste the token in the command line, hit enter  and you should get this

```
✅  registry-creds was successfully configured
```

And then add `imagePullSecrets` to your file

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: supercoolcontainer
        image: yoursupercoolregistry.azurecr.io/supercoolimage:1.0.2
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: dpr-secret
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue while using Airflow's kubernetespod operator to spin up tasks and pull images from azure container registry. What worked for me was to st up a token under repository permissions on the azure portal and use the token to set up secret in the correct namespace.[microsoft documentation on creating tokens to access azure repository images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-repository-scoped-permissions)

The docker username should be set to the name of the token
and docker password should be set to the password generated on the portal.

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry acr-secret -n namespace --docker-server=myregistry.azurecr.io --docker-username=<token-name>    --docker-password=<my-password-generated-online>
```

My earlier approach setting my username and password I use to access the azure portal as the kubernetes docker secret was incorrect.

Once this is complete I also had to update my code to include the image_pull_secrets parameter.

```
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s

run_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
 namespace=namespace,
 image=f"myregistry.azurecr.io/image-name:{image_version}",
 image_pull_policy="Always",
 image_pull_secrets=[k8s.V1LocalObjectReference("acr-secret")],
 name=f"run_my_task",
 task_id=f"run_my_task",
 get_logs=True,
)
```